# Циклы for в Python

Tags: python

Всем добрый день. Подскажите, вот есть 2 списка:

```
f = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
s = ['раз', 'два', 'три', 'четыре', 'пять']
```

Как вывести в таком формате:

```
1 = раз
2 = два
3 = три
4 = четыре
5 = пять
```

Попробовал, но почему-то выводится это очень много раз. Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

```
for i in range(len(f)):
    for j in range(len(s)):
        print(f[i], '=', s[j])
```

Comment: В Вашем варианте для каждого елемента списка f выводился елемент списка s. Чтобы было нормально, сделайте так: `[f[i], '=', s[i]' for i in range(len(s))]`, при условии, что длины списков одинаковы.

Comment: `for a, b in zip(f, s): print(a, '=', b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Два вложенных цикла создают все сочетания значений из первого и второго списка. Т.к. у вас списки одинаковой длины, то можно просто оставить один цикл:

```
for i in range(len(f)):
    print(f[i], '=', s[i])
```

Также вместо индексов получать попарно элементы из двух списков с помощью функции `zip`:

```
for x, y in zip(f, s):
    print(x, '=', y)
```

Comment: а как список s тоже начал выводить элементы по одному? Мы же написали for i in range(len(f)), здесь же s нет

Comment: @Евгений i - это просто число (индекс), которое изменяется от 0 до длины списка минус 1. Вы подставляете этот индекс в первый список - получаете элемент из первого списка. Подставляете во второй список - получаете элемент из второго списка.

Comment: Подскажите, как можно из двух списков сделать 1 список, в котором и буду значения в таком формате: 1 = раз, 2 = два и т.д.? `f = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
s = ['раз', 'два', 'три', 'четыре', 'пять']
res = []

for i, j in zip(f, s):
    res.append(f[i], '=', s[j])
print(res)`

Comment: `res.append(f[i], '=', s[j])` заменить на `res.append(f'{i} = {j}')`

Answer (score 2):

Вложенный цикл лишний. Вы выводите для каждого значения листа `f` все значения листа `s`. Достаточно одного цикла из-за соответствия позиций.

```
f = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
s = ['раз', 'два', 'три', 'четыре', 'пять']

for i in range(len(f)):
    print(f[i], '=', s[i])

# 1 = раз
# 2 = два
# 3 = три
# 4 = четыре
# 5 = пять
```

Comment: Могли бы объяснить, как, обратившись к s[i] он тоже начал выводить по одному? Почему тогда мы не написали for i in range(len(s))?

Comment: Нет разницы между `len(s)` и `len(f)`. Потому что у них одинаковая длина.